# Trouble Parsing HTML

Tags: python, regex, parsing, beautifulsoup

I currently have a large HTML file filled with directories that I have to parse and extract the names, addresses, zip-codes, phone numbers, alternative phone numbers, and etc, where I will then put the contents inside an array. Some of these directory listings (like the snippet shown below) are less challenging and straightforward to parse.

```
<span style="font-family: b'CUQZKJ+GaramondPremrPro-LtDisp'; font-size:12px">Aletheia House
<br>201 Finley Avenue West
<br>Birmingham, AL 35204
<br>(205) 324-6502x22
<br>Intake: (205) 324-6502
</span>
```

**Sample Array Output**

```
["Aletheia House", "201 Finley Avenue West",
 "Birmingham, AL 35204", "(205) 324-6502x22", "Intake: (205) 324-6502"]
```

---

However, with scenarios like the snippet below, I am currently facing issues figuring out a way to go about parsing a scenario using BeautifulSoup, Python and RegEx.

```
<span style="font-family: b'CUQZKJ+GaramondPremrPro-LtDisp'; font-size:12px">Alcohol and Drug Abuse
<br>Treatment Centers Inc/Pearson Hall
<br>2701 Jefferson Avenue SW
<br>Birmingham, AL 35211
<br>(205) 923-6552x12
<br>Intakes: (205) 923-6552x10 (205) 923-
<br>6552x13
</span>
```

**Sample Array Output:**

```
["Alcohol and Drug Abuse Treatment Centers Inc/Pearson Hall", 
 "2701 Jefferson Avenue SW", "Birmingham, AL 35211", "(205) 923-6552x12",
 "Intakes: (205) 923-6552x10 (205) 923-6552x13"]
```

Thank you!

Comment: Requests-html (https://html.python-requests.org/) looks like a viable solution to your issue.

Comment: Can you look through your data set and figure out what the variations look like? Are they all like either your first or second sample? Or are there other variations to be aware of?

Comment: it so random, try another source maybe.

Comment: Please add the code you are using to get the current results.

Comment: Are your sample outputs what you want or not what you want? It is not clear.

Comment: i think you can extract all string and regroup them by their position in array.